# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error searching wildcard

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-like

I am trying to do a query to search all name with giving letter with wild card and placeholder

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM article WHERE name LIKE %(?)%", (letter,)).fetchall()
```

but I am keep getting this error

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must concatenate the wildcards to the placeholder:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM article WHERE name LIKE '%' || ? || '%'", (letter,)).fetchall()
```

Comment: Or `'... LIKE ?', (f'%{letter}%',)`, which I find more sensible.

Comment: @darknator you missed the single quotes.

Comment: ya your right are there any documentation online i cant seem to found any

Comment: @deceze I always use ? placeholders. If possible I try to avoid format strings and string interpolation  for sql queries.

Comment: @darknator this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html